# What kind of AWS database should I use to create queryable index database off of files in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, indexing

I'm new to using AWS services and have been trying to read and learn about different database options provided by AWS but being new to the whole database thing I'm overwhelmed.

I would need to create a data lake containing hundreds of thoudands JSON files. The JSON files contain a metadata part and an actual data part and they are of the following form:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "keyA":"valueA",
    "keyB":"valueB",
    "keyC":"valueC"
  },
  "data": {
    actual data...
  }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is to create a database containing the information only found in the metadata part with some tool in AWS.

My needs for this database include:

1. Being able to find the object keys of files within s3 bucket with specific values on single or multiple keys found from metadata. Say for example I need to get access to the data from every file that has keyA value of "1" and keyB value of "True".
2. As more files of similar form are added to the bucket, I would need to be able to automatize AWS lambda to add a new line into this database.

What is the most suitable database option found from AWS for this need?

Answer (score 1):

[Elasticsearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/), while not necessarily the cheapest option, is probably going to provide you the most flexibility for search queries. You can easily connect S3 events, such as object created or object deleted, to AWS Lambda functions that will maintain the Elasticsearch indexes.